# How can I get the foreground Window using batch?

Tags: windows, powershell, getforegroundwindow

I tried to get the foreground Window and write it in a file.
After a few tries, I've only got the task list.
Now I discovered this Code, but it won't work for me:

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Tricks {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@

$a = [tricks]::GetForegroundWindow()

get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have is a Powershell snippet. Save that file as `something.ps1` or run it from `cmd.exe` with this:

```
powershell something.ps1
```